# Excel VBA loop Column, search for str, on find open workbook, copy range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

i have a little problem. I work in product development and manage 100+ projects a year, the runtime of an given project is fluid, some take longer then planed to finish and others are quicker. For every project a time/cost workbook is setup with planed costs/time and then once the project is done the actual costs/time are imputed. Up until now every table has been manualy created, filled out and saved to a folder, the files are never named the same and end up with the different title formats. This makes reviewing the yearly average cost/runtime of projects very hard.

The idea is to make the creation of the time/cost workbooks simpler.

The Workflow:

1. Open Workbook "Projects"
2. Enter Project-Nr.: xxx-yyyy-zz in Column A
                   (xxx = Project-Nr. | yyyy = year | zz = Project-type)
3. Enter Project-Name in Column B
4. Select Row with Project hit Button"Create_Open"
5. New Workbook is created using template
6. Project-Nr. and Project-Name are copied into Template
7. Workbook is saved with filename (Project-Nr. "_" Project-Name ".xml")

That part was simple enough, code bellow, it doesn't look very nice but it gets the job done.

```
Function FileExists(FullFileName As String) As Boolean
     'returns TRUE if the file exists
     FileExists = Len(Dir(FullFileName)) > 0
End Function



Sub Create_Workbook()

Dim selRow As Integer
Dim file_path As String
Dim file_extension As String

file_path = "...dir"                                    ' Speicherpfad festlegen
file_extension = ".xls"                                 ' Speichermedium festlegen

selRow = ActiveCell.Row 'aktive Zeile finden
    If Range("A" & selRow) = "" Then   ' prüfen ob Zeile ein Projekt enthält
        MsgBox ("Bitte eine ausgefullte Zeile auswählen")
        End
    End If

project_nr = Mid(Range("A" & selRow), 1, 11) ' zuweisen Projekt-Nr.
project_be = Mid(Range("B" & selRow), 1, 100) ' zuweisen Projekt Bezeichnung

'If Workbook Exists Open if not Create and write to Workbook
If Not FileExists(file_path & project_nr & "_" & project_be & file_extension) Then
   'Workbook null setzen und Template laden
    Set new_workbook = Nothing 'null setzen
    Set new_workbook = Workbooks.Add(Template:="dir") 'Postfach laufwerk einstellen

    'Projekt-Nr. und Projektbezeichnung in Controllingblatt speichern
    Range("C1") = project_be 'Projektbezeichnung setzen
    Range("C2") = project_nr 'Projektnummer setzen
    Range("C3") = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") 'Heutiges Datum setzen

    'Workbook speichern "Projekt-Nr._Projektbezeichnung"
    new_workbook.SaveAs Filename:=file_path & project_nr & "_" & project_be & file_extension

Else
    Workbooks.Open file_path & project_nr & "_" & project_be & file_extension
End If

End Sub
```

Now comes the part im having the mother of all problems solving. Search for a year in Column A, once a Project is found thats from teh given year the coresponding workbook is opened. A range of cells is copied from the opened Workbook to a new worksheet in the Project list Workbook. The range of Cells is pasted into the the new Worksheet thats given the name of the searched year. The search loops through all Rows of Column A until it reaches an empty Row.

Workflow:

1. Buttonclick opens Userwindow "Input year"
2. Clicking OK button without year input returns error
3. Input year cick OK button
4. Create new Worksheet with title of input year
5. Column A is searched for the Year.
6. Once a Project is found from the coresponding year that Project Workbook is opened
7. Copy a range of cells form Workbook
8. Paste the range of cells to Project list Workbook in the worksheet from step 4
9. close workbook opened in step 6
10. Loop 5-9 until emty cell

What i have so far isn't much at all(code bellow), i have come up against a solid wall.
I'm wondering if anyone could help me out, or if my logic is totaly flawed and i should start from scratch and build the system up differently.

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
    If Len(Me.TextBox1 & "") = 0 Then   ' prüfen ob Zeile ein Projekt enthält
        MsgBox ("Bitte Jahr eingeben")
    Else
        'Loop through cells on a sheet to find strFind1
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: So if I understand correctly the problem you are having is matching the project names in Column A with the year that was input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this helps. I tried a test and I think I got it pretty close to your question. I have a projectList workbook, on sheet one I have the following values in column A

- 111-2010-222
- 222-2010-333
- 333-2010-144
- 444-2011-111
- 555-2011-222

Then I have a button named `sumProjects` and in cell `D2` I have the year I want to total. For each of the project names above I created a spreadsheet named the same, and in those spreadsheets I put some data in column `D`. Then in the click even for the `sumProjects` button I put this code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lngLR As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sh, sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i, x as Integer

    With Me
        lngLR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'finds the last row of column A
    End With

    'creates a new worksheet with the name of the given year
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set sh = .Worksheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        sh.Name = (Range("D2").Value)
    End With

    x = 1 'this will be used to keep track if which row to input
          'data on the destination sheet, we set it to 1 because
          'we know the destination sheet is a new sheet so we know
          'where the first row is, we do not have to calculate it

    'loops through all of the project names in column A
    'looking for one that contains the year given in D2
    For i = 1 To lngLR
        'look for year in project name 
        If InStr(Range("A" & i), Range("D2")) Then
            'project of given year found. Open workbook and get data
            Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\" & Range("A" & i) & ".xlsx")
            Set sourceSheet = wb.Worksheets(1)
            sh.Range("C" & x).Value = sourceSheet.Range("D5").Value
            x = x + 1 'x is only incremented when a value is placed on the new sheet
            wb.Close
        End If
    Next i 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the Code and Response, had a long weekend, sorry it took me so long to reply. The following code is giving me some truble    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  it returns a compilation Error, Method or Dataobject not found(im working with a german Excel/VBA so the Error might be a bit off)

Comment: Ok so i followed your steps exactly and it works great. But once i edit the code to "work" with a Textbox input and  and use it in a userform command button it goes nuts with compilation errors.

Comment: So i got it working, thanks for the help! Now i just need to puzzle out how to add the worksheet from a template.

Answer (score 0):

So i edited loveforvdubs code to fit my needs. Im sure the copying of the Worksheet template could have been solved much more elegantly, but i couldn't get any of the other solutions to stick.

Thanks again for the help loveforvdubs!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lngLR As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh, sourceSheet As Worksheet

If Len(Me.TextBox1 & "") = 0 Then   ' If TextBox1 is empty returns Msg
    MsgBox ("Bitte Jahr eingeben")
Else
    With Me
        lngLR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'finds the last row of column A
    End With

    'creates a new worksheet with the name of the given year
    With ThisWorkbook
        Worksheets("Auswertung").Visible = True
        Worksheets("Auswertung").Select
        Worksheets("Auswertung").Copy After:=Sheets(1)
        Worksheets("Auswertung (2)").Select
        Worksheets("Auswertung (2)").Name = TextBox1
        Worksheets("Auswertung").Visible = False
        Set sh = Worksheets(2)
    End With

    'loops through all of the project names in column A
    'looking for one that contains the year given in TextBox1
    For i = 1 To lngLR
        'look for year in project name
        If InStr(Range("A" & i), TextBox1) Then
            'project of given year found. Open workbook and get data
            Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open("K:\Projektplanung\Projektkosten\" & Range("A" & i) & "_" & Range("B" & i) & ".xlsx")
            Set sourceSheet = wb.Worksheets(1)
            sh.Range("A" & i).Value = sourceSheet.Range("I30").Value
            wb.Close
        End If
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Gabe_69bird, I'm glad it's working for you. If you need the worksheet to be a certain template I think you have worked out a pretty decent solution. You could also hide the template worksheet to make it all look a bit neater. Let me know if you have any other problems. Viel Glück!

Comment: Hi @loveforvdubs, I do have one little problem. The range value from the sourcesheet is being copied to the mirrored cell on the destinationsheet(sourcesheet range is in row 6 its copied to row 6 destinationsheet). I can't seem to get it to start at row 3 for all results found and keep going.

Comment: Hey @Gabe_69bird, I'm not sure I completely understand your question. So you are having trouble with `sh.Range("A" & i).Value = sourceSheet.Range("I30").Value1`, it is not starting on the correct row?

Comment: Hey @loveforvdubs, yes it starts on the row where it finds the first instance of the Year. So if the fist instance is in row 6 it copies to row 6, if the 2nd instance is in row 8 it copies to row 8 etc..

Comment: see my edits in my answer. I added another counter to keep track of the row on the destination sheet and it is only incremented when a new value is pasted on to the destination sheet. We can start the counter at 1 since we know it's a new sheet copied from the template. If we didn't know what was on the sheet we would have to calculate the last row like we did to setup the for loop.

Comment: Glad to hear it! No problem!